# How is client side JWT signature validation beneficial from a security perspective?

Tags: encryption, digital-signature, proxy, jwt

I’ve been reading about how clients can verify JWT signatures using a public key provided by the server. I’m struggling to understand how this solves any issues.

The only attack I’ve seen which this claims to solve is when a reverse proxy issues JWTs on behalf of the server. In this case though, wouldn’t the requests for a public key also go through the proxy, which could respond with its own public key?

Am I misunderstanding reverse proxies, or are there other instances in which verifying a signature in the client would be beneficial?

I’ve looked around online for information about why client side verification is good, but have found nothing concrete.

Edit:
Unfortunately I can not find the original articles / threads which I read through, but they were not very helpful regardless. To clarify my needs. I am using a JWS to authorize users. I read that you should make your public key available via a public endpoint for a client to use to make sure that the token wasn't replaced or tampered with in transit, or issued by a reverse-proxy server. I simply don't understand how this process solves any of the security concerns listed above. If it's tampered with or replaced, this sounds like a Man-In-The-Middle attack. In this case, the MITM could return their own public key anyways. As for a reverse-proxy, my confusion is the same (attacker can respond with their own public key).

Now that I think about it, is the solution to have a certificate instead of simply a public/private key pair? If so, how?

Comment: *"I’ve been reading about how clients can verify JWT signatures ..."* - please provide more context, like a link to where you have read this. This might help to understand the problem somebody tried to solve this way. Note that JWT are used in a variety of different contexts.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I've made an edit. I hope it helps.

Comment: Not really. You still don't provide useful context for what you've read, only claim that it was not helpful. Then you explain the needs you have in your specific use case - which do not even matter for what you originally asked. So either you want to know if client side JWT validation make ever sense - then provide the context where this was claimed. Or you want to know how you should proceed in your specific use case - then ask a different question which just focuses on your use case.